# How can I fix the following Django code? Using variables within function command

Tags: python, django, variables, conditional-statements

I have got two radio buttons labeled 'equal to' and 'not equal to'. There names vary depending on the field they are set to. For example, after the Name field, there names are radio_name and the values are 'equal to' and 'not equal to'. After the Number field there names are radio_number and the values are 'equal to' and 'not equal to'. I hope this is clear. I am trying to put the conditions into a function so that I don't have to repeat myself a lot.

This is what I'm trying but it's not working:

```
def condition(radio, var):
        if radio == 'equal to':
            objs = objs.filter(var__icontains=var)
        if radio == 'not equal to':
            objs = objs.exclude(var__icontains=var)
        return objs
```

And then when calling the function:

```
if name:
        objs = condition(radio_name, name);
if number:
        objs = condition(radio_number, number);
```

I hope this is clear to all. :-/

Comment: Which part isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things should be fixed:

- you need to pass `objs` into the function
- in order to pass keyword arguments made from strings, use [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)
- no need for `;` at the end of lines

Here's the fixed version:

```
def condition(objs, radio, **kwargs):
    if radio == 'equal to':
        filters = {'%s__icontains' % key: value for key, value in kwargs.iteritems()}
        objs = objs.filter(**filters)
    if radio == 'not equal to':
        filters = {'%s__icontains' % key: value for key, value in kwargs.iteritems()}
        objs = objs.exclude(**filters)
    return objs
```

Usage:

```
if name:
    objs = condition(objs, radio_name, name=name)
if number:
    objs = condition(objs, radio_number, number=number)
```

This still has room for improvement, but I hope it helps to achieve the desired results.

Comment: Wow! Even I couldn't understand what I wrote on the question. Thanks man. This worked like a charm. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you say "it's not working," I'm a bit unclear on what the expected result is and what's actually happening. Looking over your code, one thing that jumps out is that you're checking radio == 'equal to' and so on -- if what you're feeding into it is a radio button *object* you probably have to refer to the value property of that object, e.g.:

```
if radio.value == 'equal to':
    objs = objs.filter(var__icontains=var)
```

Is the "radio" class one you built yourself, or something you're importing? If the former, you may want to consider adding a "type" field to it, so the second bit of code you put in would look like this:

```
if radio.type == 'name':
    objs = condition(radio_name, name)
elif radio.type == 'number':
    objs = condition(radio_number, number)
```

By the way, you don't need semicolons at the end of your lines if you're writing in Python; I removed them in the above code.